# Add attribute using Codedom in C#

Tags: c#, codedom

I want to add following line of code while creating page using Codedom in c#.

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "-922337203685477.5808", "922337203685477.5807", ErrorMessage = "")]
public string d3 { get; set; }
```

But not able so please let me know how can I achived it or provide any sample that explain the same.

Comment: If the problem is just getting the attribute applied, where is the rest of the code for us to make the edit to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will create the property definition you provided.

One thing to note is that automatic properties (`get; set;`) are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) provided by the C# compiler and cannot be generated by CodeDOM. To create a property you will need to provide the backing field in the traditional way.

The key to answering your question is the [`CodeAttributeDeclaration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeattributedeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
const string fieldName = "_d3";

// Create the backing field for the property.
var field = new CodeMemberField(typeof(string), fieldName);

// Create the property.
var prop = new CodeMemberProperty();
prop.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final; // Public, non-virtual.
prop.Name = "d3";
prop.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(string));
prop.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(fieldName)));
prop.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(fieldName), new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("value")));

// Create the attribute declaration for the property.
var attr = new CodeAttributeDeclaration(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute)));
attr.Arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodeTypeOfExpression(typeof(decimal))));
attr.Arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("-922337203685477.5808")));
attr.Arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("922337203685477.5807")));
attr.Arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument("ErrorMessage", new CodePrimitiveExpression("")));
prop.CustomAttributes.Add(attr);

// Create a class to contain the property.
var testClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("TestClass");
testClass.Members.Add(field);   // Add the backing field.
testClass.Members.Add(prop);    // Add the property.
```

Executing this code will result in your property being generated in the `code` variable (wrapped in a test class).

```
string code;
using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    provider.GenerateCodeFromType(testClass, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions() { BracingStyle = "C" });
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    code = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Contents of the `code` variable:

```
public class TestClass
{

    private string _d3;

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute(typeof(decimal), "-922337203685477.5808", "922337203685477.5807", ErrorMessage="")]
    public string d3
    {
        get
        {
            return _d3;
        }
        set
        {
            _d3 = value;
        }
    }
}
```